# Set random Rails variable to not equal another random variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random

I have 2 instance variables in a Rails controller:

```
@stories = Post.tagged_with("test").all(:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 1)
@stories2 = Post.tagged_with("test").where('post_id not in (?)', [@stories]).all(:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 1)
```

I don't want the other instance variable to equal the other but they both have to be "random" (I know this technically isn't random). Is it possible to set a variable random except one value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@stories, @stories2 = Post.tagged_with("test").all(order: "RANDOM()", limit: 2)
```

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! How can I use this in an each loop? I get undefined method for each with this statement: `<% @stories.each do |story| %>`

Comment: You are fetching one record by specifying `:limit => 1` but you want to use `.each` on it?

Comment: That's true, I guess I don't need the .each. So if I want to use the data from the variable, what would I use? Just @stories.element?

Comment: Remove lines of code related to iteration `.each do ...` , `<% end %>` and use your `@stories` variable instead of `story` in code, which used to be inside `each` block.
And you'd better rename `@stories` to `@story`. Cause that's what it is: one story

Comment: GOT IT! Disregard other questions. You guys were a huge help! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You could make the second query return 2, and do some logic to check for equivalency

```
@stories = Post.tagged_with("test").all(:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 1)
@stories2 = Post.tagged_with("test").where('post_id not in (?)', [@stories]).all(:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 1)

@stories2.delete_at(@stories[0] == @stories2[0] ? 0 : 1);
```

With the above code, if the single element from the first object is the same as that of the second, we delete it and use the other.  If they are not the same, we delete the "extra" story we have in the second array.  At the end, each instance variable will have one item in the array, and they will not be the same.